# Ping a host using Python

Tags: python, ip, ping

I am new at python and not pretty much familiar with python syntax. My issue is i am trying to developing an app (on console) that can ping different (user defined) IPs and the ip which is pinging correctly so just simply print "Host Is Available" but the ip which is not responding generate the message "Host Is not Available", and automatically in every 5 minutes. I am trying to do that with for loop but cant execute that what i want. Can someone help me out in this matter?

Here is my code:

```
import subprocess
import os
import ctypes # An included library with Python install.
import time
with open(os.devnull, "wb") as limbo:

        for n in xrange(1,10):
                ip="192.168.0.{0}".format(n)
                result=subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "200", ip],
                        stdout=limbo, stderr=limbo).wait() 
                if result:
                        print ip,ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, "Sorry! Host is not Available.", "Alert!", 1)


                else:
                        print ip, "Host Is Available"



print ("IP Monitor!")
time.sleep(5)

import subprocess
import os
import ctypes # An included library with Python install.
import time
with open(os.devnull, "wb") as limbo:

        for n in xrange(1,10):
                ip="192.168.0.{0}".format(n)
                result=subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "200", ip],
                        stdout=limbo, stderr=limbo).wait() 
                if result:
                        print ip,ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, "Sorry! Host is not Available.", "Alert!", 1)


                else:
                        print ip, "Host Is Available"



input()
```

Comment: Do you really have the same code twice, `import`s and all?

Comment: yes because as i said i want it to run continuously in back ground to like looping check ips but cant figure it out how? so i hard coded to repetition.

Comment: @HarisBinZahid Why not `while True: # code here`

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a call to `communicate()` right after creating the `Popen` object:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def host_is_available(ip):
    '''
    Pings a host and return True if it is available, False if not.
    '''
    cmd = ['ping', '-c', '1', '-t', '1', ip]
    process = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
    return process.returncode == 0 # code=0 means available

ip = '192.168.1.2'
if host_is_available(ip):
    print '{} is available'.format(ip)
else:
    print '{} is not available'.format(ip)
```

## Discussion

- The `Popen()` creates an object (a process), but do not execute the command
- To execute that command, you need to call `communicate()`
- `communicate()` returns `stdout` and `stderr`, you can discard them or use them
- You don't need to open `os.devnull` in order to discard the output
- Now that you know how to ping one host, you should not have any problem with multiple hosts

Comment: exactly i don't have any problem with multiple hosts but the problem is  once loop complete it dosen't repeat itself again n again what i actually want.

Answer (score 1):

To keep something running forever, you want an endless loop, not a `for` loop.

Here's how to run something five times:

```
for i in (xrange 5):
    ... do stuff ...
```

or generally loop over anything with a suitable number of items:

```
for personality in ['openness', 'conscientiousness', 'extraversion',
                    'agreeableness', 'neuroticism']:
    ... do stuff ...
```

Here's how to do something forever:

```
while True:
   ... do stuff ...
```

or equivalently (but obscurely) any true condition will do:

```
while 1 != 0:
    ... do stuff ...
```

Commonly, you do initialization first, then run the loop.  So, taking into account the answer from @HaiVu, your entire code would look something like this:

```
import subprocess
import os
import ctypes
import time

print ("IP Monitor!")

while True:
    for n in xrange(1,10):
       ip="192.168.0.{0}".format(n)
       process = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "200", ip],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
       stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
       if process.returncode != 0:
           print ip,ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0,
               "Sorry! Host is not Available.", "Alert!", 1)
       else:
           print ip, "Host Is Available"

   time.sleep(5)
```

The mixing of regular `print` with an OS-specific message box seems misdirected (and I have no idea what the `print` of the message box produces; and the message box is kind of useless without the IP address and perhaps a time stamp in the message) but hopefully this should at least get you started.

Comment: thats not even worked for me. wanna run this code endless time until or unless user close the application? like user once open the app it starts pinging given ips keep run once, twice and so on after specified time until user close the application by himself. the entire code should repeat itself again n again. i dont wanna hard code the same code many times.

Comment: Apart from having to use different IP addresses and `ping` options, and disabling the message box code, it works for me.  (Invalid `ping` options would make it seem to simply hang, though.  Does this `ping` command line work for your platform in the shell?) http://pastebin.com/S276HaFA

Comment: i have find out the problem.. just need to put while = 1 instead of while true and bingo... its working fine (endless loop) what i actually want and also generating a pop up alert on non responding host.. but anyways thanks for every one to contribute and your precious advises.

Comment: That's incorrect syntax. I don't think you have transcribed that correctly.

Comment: tripleee yes you are right thats my typing mistake actually it is while 1 not while = 1.